# I am Confused in basics

Tags: signal-analysis

> **WHAT IS** signal means, **how is** it propagate in space or any other medium?.
>
> > what power means signal amplitude increases and decreases to draw the sine wave form through a bit of time. at stable value (forming logical message) **affected by** medium resistance and transmitting signal power, human code model frequently repeated (hi) started with character ends with another completed word (world) another word stared with a header and ends with trailer a completed word in between. the brain define (h) as code start and (i) as its end then put a definition for it as a welcome category word means how are you.

**out of electricity network** that it out of control compared with communication signals networks even both of them propagate as a flood of electrons in cables, need a **Summarized Signal Theory Basics paper shows** its shape in a medium, MW or Electromagnetic waves or in cables.

> voice fades away at the moment you shot a word. you already carried it on a carrier to reach ear of who you talk to but at low power so that its power and frequency decreased and lose its shape at a point seems to be disappeared or **absorbed to be converted to another shape of energy.**
> power - amplitude - frequency - energy (essences needed to be learned)
>
> > we carries it on a carrier varies depending on the medium and convert carrier to cover all values voice reach as possible, more values means more quality. filtering the result to get carrier and voice met points.

just comments needed, books and papers.

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: Hi! This sadly is not a "comments needed" site, but a site very much tailored towards *getting answers to precise questions*; so, I'm afraid you'll have to *ask a precise question*.

Comment: i mean answers in comment with explanation for signal analysis basics.

Comment: i mean answer in comment how can i find basics related to my background.

Comment: this question is a duplicate of this https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/48032/need-a-mobile-signals-essence-discusion/48051#48051 which he just asked

Comment: better to give an answer for his quesion

Comment: any way, i will find it .bye